# How to include two SSAS cube fields of same name in SSRS report

Tags: tfs, ssas, mdx, ssrs-2012

I am using the query designer tool within SSRS to build an MDX query against the TFS analysis cube.  I am trying to query some data within TFS 2013.  My query returns what I need, however, when I attempt to close the query designer to return to my report I get the following error message:

> The query contains more than one unnamed or duplicate field name. 
>   Please specify unique column aliases

The problem is that I want to include the `System_Title` field from the `Work Item` tree and the `System_Title` field from the `Work Item Linked` tree.

How can I include both of these `System_Title` fields in my SSRS report?

Here is my MDX for reference

```
  SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_RemainingWork]
    , [Measures].[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_OriginalEstimate]
    , [Measures].[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork] } 
        ON COLUMNS
    , NON EMPTY { ([Work Item].[System_AssignedTo].[System_AssignedTo].ALLMEMBERS 
    * [Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].[System_WorkItemType].ALLMEMBERS 
    * [Work Item].[Iteration Path].[Iteration Path].ALLMEMBERS 
    * [Work Item].[Area Path].[Area Path].ALLMEMBERS 
    * [Work Item Linked].[System_Title].[System_Title].ALLMEMBERS 
    * [Work Item].[System_Title].[System_Title].ALLMEMBERS 
    * [Work Item].[System_State].[System_State].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION
    , MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( 
        SELECT ( STRTOSET(@WorkItemIterationPath, CONSTRAINED) ) 
            ON COLUMNS 
            FROM ( 
                SELECT ( STRTOSET(@WorkItemAreaPath, CONSTRAINED) ) 
                    ON COLUMNS FROM [Team System])) 
                    CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
                    , BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR
                    , FORMATTED_VALUE
                    , FORMAT_STRING
                    , FONT_NAME
                    , FONT_SIZE
                    , FONT_FLAGS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default your field names are set to the attribute name. You can change this by going to the field names and putting in a different field name for one of the two System_Title fields.

1. Right click on the data set in the Datasets folder.
2. Choose Dataset Properties.
3. Go to the Fields page.
4. Change the Field Name.
5. Click OK.

[image]

Comment: I had to change the first field's name, go back to the query and add the second field, and this worked.  Thanks.